# Facebook "Like" of snippets of data rather than whole pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I've been looking at OpenGraph API and other FB Developers documentation, but can't really see if it's possible to attach FB "Like" and/or "Share" buttons to snippets of data on a page.

I've only ever seen whole page implementations. I.e. when you "Like" a blog article for example, you're actually liking a specific page (the blog post). However, I have several pieces of information on a single page (they don't link anywhere) and wondered if I could get my users to interact with that? So they'd be liking a section within a page? Using anchors to  link back..

Is this possible or does it not even make sense?

P

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are looking for "social interaction web tracking". Take a look here http://www.seosandwitch.com/2013/03/how-to-track-facebook-likes-in-google.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for the response and link.. While the article is informative, it's also saying the same thing: "layman terms, you can track the number of Facebook likes from each of your individual pages" - I'm not interested in tracking individual PAGES, but snippets of content on a static page.

Comment: If you can go with solution where every snippet has it's own page, then I don't see a problem here. Just generate like buttons with correct url for the snippet and put all snippets in one page.I don't think that it will be some violation of Facebook terms because each Like button will have correct and distinct  target url.

Comment: My question was about the possiblity of adding "Like" buttons to pieces of data on a SINGLE page. I guess what you and most olf the articles I've read are saying is that, you can only "Like" a specific page, not multiple elements within a single page. I.e. Each "Like" corresponds to a unique URL. Cheers!

Comment: Take a closer look at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/. Generate a button and you will see that "custom" url can be placed in the data-href tag. So it should be possible for you to generate as many buttons on the single page as you want by placing url of correct snippet. Think of it as a blog site where in one page summary of all blog articles are displayed and all articles has like button attached to it.